# Different response status codes for ConstraintViolationException

Tags: spring, validation

So. In my spring app, In service I validate some objects, and if it invalid, throw ConstraintViolationException

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<ImageRequest>> violations = validator.validate(imageRequest);
    if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
        throw new ConstraintViolationException(violations);
    }
```

and in @ControllerAdvice it handled by

```
@ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
ValidationErrorResponse onConstraintValidationException(
        ConstraintViolationException e) {
    ValidationErrorResponse error = new ValidationErrorResponse();
    for (ConstraintViolation violation : e.getConstraintViolations()) {
        error.getErrors().put(
                violation.getPropertyPath().toString(), violation.getMessage());
    }
    return error;
}
```

The problem is that sometimes I need return different status codes of response for ConstraintViolationException(It depends on type of object on which generated ConstraintViolationException). How can i achieve it? P.S. Sorry for English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. remove `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)`
2. Approach A

```
@ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
@ResponseBody
ValidationErrorResponse onConstraintValidationException(
        ConstraintViolationException e, HttpServletResponse response) {
    ValidationErrorResponse error = new ValidationErrorResponse();
    for (ConstraintViolation violation : e.getConstraintViolations()) {
        error.getErrors().put(
                violation.getPropertyPath().toString(), violation.getMessage());
    }
    response.setStatus(..based on some condition set status code ..);
    return error;
}
```

2. Approach B(IMHO: much better)

```
@ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
ResponseEntity<ValidationErrorResponse> onConstraintValidationException(
        ConstraintViolationException e) {
    ValidationErrorResponse error = new ValidationErrorResponse();
    for (ConstraintViolation violation : e.getConstraintViolations()) {
        error.getErrors().put(
                violation.getPropertyPath().toString(), violation.getMessage());
    }
    return ResponseEntity.status(..desired status..).body(error);
}
```

Comment: I understand that I can make decision which status code of response will be in the mehtod which handle ConstraintViolationException, but I would like that methot which handle ConstraintViolationException didn't have any logic of which status code of response shoud be. Is there I way I can define my custom Exception with a Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> and handle this custom Exception in @ContollerAdvice?

Comment: @frigoshor just create a custom exception with set of constraint violations and handle this exception